# Can I receive an email notification when someone submits a form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to receive an email notification when someone submits a form. I am on the free version.

Answer (score 1):

> Turn on this option to allow form administrators to be notified via
>   email every time a user submits your form. Email notification options
>   can set by clicking the Submission Settings button at the bottom of
>   your Form's Build page. Your form's submission settings will display
>   in the left-hand pane.
>
> Click the corresponding On/Off button to enable Notification Emails.
>   The first time you create a notification email, the notification email
>   dialog will appear. Fill out the appropriate fields and then click the
>   Save button.
>
> **Individual plans can have only one email notification per form.**
>
> To create an additional notifications, click the New Email link at the
>   bottom of the Email Notifications section when that section is
>   expanded. By default, this section will be collapsed and clicking on
>   the title of the section will expand it so you can see all of the
>   notifications.

[Notification Emails](http://help.cognitoforms.com/notification-emails)